# Developing app for old Nokia phone

Tags: nokia

I want to develop apps for non smartphone Nokia phone, really the elementary ones found at the market right now like the Nokia 1800. Is it possible? Links to such will be appreciated.

Comment: Nokia non-smartphones are generally S40, not Symbian.  It would be helpful if you specified a particular model.

Comment: Well I have a Nokia 1800 , which is really at the entry level , any hopes of developing apps for it on the client side .

Comment: The [Nokia 1800](http://europe.nokia.com/find-products/devices/nokia-1800/specifications) is an S30 device, *not* Symbian. If third-party apps are even possible, your best bet would probably be Java. I've never worked on such devices myself.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, Symbian phones have been smartphones since early 2000s.

Anyway...
If you want native (Series60) Symbian OS apps install Carbide from Nokia.
If your phone supports QT then get QT Creator. There are videos from Nokia on youTube about how to install and configure it. Both are free.

Comment: Thanks mate , well I will do some digging .